# Using ScrollView is not showing my List data

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

In below code I want to implement a ScrollView as I don't know how many items will be in my List. Problem is that nothing of the list is shown when running.
If I remove the ScrollView my List becomes visible.
What am I missing here:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView() {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    List {
                        ForEach(1..<10) { i in
                            Text("\(i) SomeItem")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("ScrollViewTest")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Using Xcode 14.2, no extensions.

Comment: List already scrolls. The ScrollView is pointless in this case.

Comment: add a `.frame(...)` to the `List`, e.g. `List{...}.frame(width: 333, height: 444)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use ScrollView or a VStack with a List, since List already loads its views lazily. You can see how the "CustomView" is loaded in the example below.

```
struct ScrollViewTest: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(1..<10000) { i in
                    CustomView(number: i)
                    
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("ScrollViewTest")
        }
    }
}

struct CustomView: View {
    
    init(number: Int) {
        self.number = number
        print("\(number) is loaded") // <- check how the views are loaded lazily while scrolling in the list
    }
    
    let number: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(number) SomeItem")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working now. I still have a question: Why is it not working in a ScrollView?